# Concatenate a JSON string with another string in Python

Tags: json, python-2.7, amazon-ec2

I have a dictionary as below

```
(Pdb) interface_list
[{'DeviceIndex': 0, 'NetworkInterfaceId': u'eni-2b9dcb04', 'DeleteOnTermination': True}, {'DeviceIndex': 1, 'NetworkInterfaceId': u'eni-289dcb07', 'DeleteOnTermination': True}]
```

Now I converted this to a JSON string as below,

```
(pdb)!interface_list1 = json.dumps(interface_list)
(pdb)interface_list1
'[{"DeviceIndex": 0, "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-2b9dcb04", "DeleteOnTermination": true}, {"DeviceIndex": 1, "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-289dcb07", "DeleteOnTermination": true}]'
(Pdb) type(interface_list1)
<type 'str'>
```

Now I tried to  concatenate  this JSON string with another string as below,

```
(Pdb) !cmd = "aws ec2 run-instances --instance-type " + Image_type + " --network-interfaces " + interface_list1 + " --image-id " + Ami_ID + " --no-verify-ssl --endpoint-url " + end_point_url
(Pdb) cmd
'aws ec2 run-instances --instance-type m3.large --network-interfaces [{"DeviceIndex": 0, "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-2b9dcb04", "DeleteOnTermination": true}, {"DeviceIndex": 1, "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-289dcb07", "DeleteOnTermination": true}] --image-id ami-879f4bec --no-verify-ssl --endpoint-url https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
```

It's not adding quotes around the following,

```
 '[{"DeviceIndex": 0, "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-2b9dcb04", "DeleteOnTermination": true}, {"DeviceIndex": 1, "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-289dcb07", "DeleteOnTermination": true}]'
```

Because of this issue when I do system command execute I get an error it's not in required format by aws cli command.

How can I concatenate with quotes around my interface_list1 variable?

Note:
I have tried the following,

```
cmd = "aws ec2 run-instances --instance-type \'" + Image_type + "\' --network-interfaces " + interface_list1 + " --image-id " + Ami_ID + " --no-verify-ssl --endpoint-url " + end_point_url
```

But \' is also getting concatenated and so again aws cli is not accepting slash . So I don't want the slash but I wanted the single quote '. Double quotes also not accepted by aws cli.

Comment: *"concordinate"* - concatenate?!

Comment: concatenate , have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I think you're combining multiple encodings, as indicated by that there is a `u` in front of one of your strings in the dictionary. [Check out this module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html) and `normalize` all your strings before concatenating them.

Comment: when I do interface_list1 = json.dumps(interface_list) its converting to string and removes unicode (u)

Comment: Decode all strings to ascii before concatenating: `str1.decode('ascii') + 'literal_string'.decode('ascii')` -- if that works then you know that multiple encodings were the problem.

Comment: Tried to decode but it always adds \' even thought i just add only ' when i concatenate like http://pastebin.com/tp7b7wGS